# How to create a ranking column based on date value range in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, ranking

```
data = [
    ["Item_1", "2020-06-01"],
    ["Item_1", "2020-06-02"],
    ["Item_1", "2020-05-27"],
    ["Item_2", "2018-04-15"],
    ["Item_2", "2018-04-18"],
    ["Item_2", "2018-04-22"],
    ["Item_2", "2018-04-28"],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Item_ID", "Dates"])
df
```

I have a dataset containing a column of `Item IDs` and `Dates`. I would like to assign a "ranking" of sorts in a new column, where the rank/order value is increased **IF** the next date is >3 days from the previous date, otherwise it stays the same.

So the desired output would look like this:

```
    Item_ID    Dates    Date Order
    Item_1  2020-05-27      1
    Item_1  2020-06-01      2
    Item_1  2020-06-02      2 
    Item_2  2018-04-15      1
    Item_2  2018-04-18      1
    Item_2  2018-04-22      2 
    Item_2  2018-04-28      3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `groupby apply` to compute the difference per group between days, then use `cumsum` on the to "count" how many differences are greater than (`gt) 3 days:

```
# Convert to datetime (if not already)
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])
# Sort in correct order
df = df.sort_values(['Item_ID', 'Dates'], ignore_index=True)
# Calculate Ranking per Group
df['Date Order'] = (
    df.groupby('Item_ID')['Dates'].apply(
        lambda s: s.diff().gt(pd.Timedelta(days=3)).cumsum() + 1
    )
)
```

---

Could also `groupby` twice and use [`groupby diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) and [`groupby cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
# Convert to datetime (if not already)
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])
# Sort in correct order
df = df.sort_values(['Item_ID', 'Dates'], ignore_index=True)

# Reuse same Grouper
g = df.groupby('Item_ID') 
# Calculate Difference per group and compare (whole Series)
df['Date Order'] = g['Dates'].diff().gt(pd.Timedelta(days=3))
# Calculate cumsum per group
df['Date Order'] = g['Date Order'].cumsum() + 1
```

Both produce `df`:

```
  Item_ID      Dates  Date Order
0  Item_1 2020-05-27           1
1  Item_1 2020-06-01           2
2  Item_1 2020-06-02           2
3  Item_2 2018-04-15           1
4  Item_2 2018-04-18           1
5  Item_2 2018-04-22           2
6  Item_2 2018-04-28           3
```

---

Here is a breakdown of the steps per group as a DataFrame:

```
s = pd.Series([pd.Timestamp('2020-05-27 00:00:00'),
               pd.Timestamp('2020-06-01 00:00:00'),
               pd.Timestamp('2020-06-02 00:00:00')],
              name='Dates',
              index=pd.Series({0: 'Item_1', 1: 'Item_1', 2: 'Item_1'},
                              name='Item_ID'))
steps_per_group = pd.DataFrame({
    'diff': s.diff(),
    'gt': s.diff().gt(pd.Timedelta(days=3)),
    'cumsum': s.diff().gt(pd.Timedelta(days=3)).cumsum(),
    'cumsum 1 start': s.diff().gt(pd.Timedelta(days=3)).cumsum() + 1
})
```

```
          diff     gt  cumsum  cumsum 1 start
Item_ID                                      
Item_1     NaT  False       0               1
Item_1  5 days   True       1               2
Item_1  1 days  False       1               2
```

Answer (score 1):

From your `DataFrame` :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> data = [
...     ["Item_1", "2020-05-27"],
...     ["Item_1", "2020-06-01"],
...     ["Item_1", "2020-06-02"],
...     ["Item_2", "2018-04-15"],
...     ["Item_2", "2018-04-18"],
...     ["Item_2", "2018-04-22"],
...     ["Item_2", "2018-04-28"],
... ]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Item_ID", "Dates"])
>>> df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'], format="%Y-%m-%d")
>>> df
    Item_ID     Dates
0   Item_1  2020-05-27
1   Item_1  2020-06-01
2   Item_1  2020-06-02
3   Item_2  2018-04-15
4   Item_2  2018-04-18
5   Item_2  2018-04-22
6   Item_2  2018-04-28
```

We can get the date `diff` grouped by `Item_ID` like so :

```py
>>> window_size = 3
>>> df['diff'] = df.groupby('Item_ID')["Dates"].diff().dt.days.gt(window_size)
>>> df
    Item_ID     Dates   diff
0   Item_1  2020-05-27  False
1   Item_1  2020-06-01  True
2   Item_1  2020-06-02  False
3   Item_2  2018-04-15  False
4   Item_2  2018-04-18  False
5   Item_2  2018-04-22  True
6   Item_2  2018-04-28  True
```

Then, by grouping again by `Item_ID` and applying a `cumsum`, we get the expected result :

```py
>>> df['Date Order'] = df.groupby('Item_ID')["diff"].cumsum()+1
>>> df
    Item_ID     Dates   diff    Date Order
0   Item_1  2020-05-27  False   1
1   Item_1  2020-06-01  True    2
2   Item_1  2020-06-02  False   2
3   Item_2  2018-04-15  False   1
4   Item_2  2018-04-18  False   1
5   Item_2  2018-04-22  True    2
6   Item_2  2018-04-28  True    3
```